# ActiveMQ and other FOSS JMS Implementation for Android

Tags: android, jms

I'm doing an academic project which focus on providing some enhanced “LBS” services for Android.  To do that, we are making a small middleware. The core communication of it uses a MOM (in our implementation --> JMS).

I’ve used ActiveMQ JMS implementation using JNDI connectivity, in the past, and it seems that isn’t available on Android. I searched on the web and I found some topics on using the XMPP protocol as a transport mean to communicate with the event broker.

The problem is that I never worked with XMPP, and it seems that it’s really not trivial compared to “standard”usage. Is it really that different than “standard” JNDI/ActiveMQ? Also, are there other FOSS JMS implementations for Android that are easy to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With ActiveMQ you could use STOMP as a protocol. its much simpler than xmpp.

there doesn't seem to be a native stomp implementation for android (there are several for java). But the spec only has one page so this shouldnt be a problem.

Another alternative might be RabbitMQ. I remember a news about a rabbitMQ library for Android systems.